# What are the special letters?

Tags: letter-sequence

You are presented with five groups of five words. All of the letters in each word share a common trait, except for one. The rule governing which letter is different is consistent within each group.

The unique letters in each group spell a word. Applying the group's rule to that word produces a single meta-letter. Use the five meta-letters to find the meta-word which answers the title question.

```
asia
maui
scratch
eerie
auto


blacklight
foreshadow
dynasty
napalm
roleplaying


gasped
deadbeat
horticulturist
bagpipe
decoded


corrupt
snowplow
nervous
yawn
challengeable


perpetrator
without
falafel
equator
tidy
```

Bonus: What is the meta-meta-letter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. smart (only vowel/consonant) > a
>  2. loyal (double letter) > l
>  3. stoic (only letter with/without “hole” in it) > o
>  4. clean (only letter in its half of the alphabet) > n
>  5. ahead (only letter on its row on keyboard) > e
>  Putting it together: alone > l (only letter reaching top of line height, also, "l is the loneliest number")

Credit @deusovi for group 5 solution.

Comment: Nice work! Everything is correct except for the bonus. The case of the words was chosen purposefully.

Comment: How bout that? @jamisans

Comment: That's the one I was thinking of!

Answer (score 1):

asia, maui, scratch, eerie, auto

> Each word has all letters consonants but one, or all letters vowels but one. The out-of-place letters spell SMART.

blacklight, foreshadow, dynasty, napalm, roleplaying

> Each letter appears exactly once except one; the letters that appear twice spell LOYAL.

gasped, deadbeat, horticulturist, bagpipe, decoded

> The word is STOIC, and the extra letter is O. I'm not sure what the property is here, but you can logically deduce that the alphabet is split in two here: one group has `abdegop` in it, and the other has `chilrstu` in it.

corrupt, snowplow, nervous, yawn, challengeable

> ???

perpetrator, without, falafel, equator, tidy

> All letters come from the same row of a QWERTY keyboard but one; the out-of-place letters spell AHEAD.

Meta-letters

> SMART's only vowel is A.
>  LOYAL's only repeated letter is L.
>  STOIC's only [???] is O.
>  ?????
>  AHEAD's only letter not on the middle row of a QWERTY keyboard is E.
>
>  The special letters are **ALONE**. Fitting for a puzzle about odd ones out!

Comment: Not sure what protocol is for this, but I credited you for part 5 in my solution; I promise I came up with the rest 